# Working With Temporary Tables in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

### Background:

I am currently writing a web front for analysis of our web logs which get inserted into SQL Server.

One of the most basic features is that it you can search for a set of results by specifying a time frame (This is generally a tool for troubleshooting recent traffic, not deep data mining) and then various other fields, such has the ClientIP, Uri, etc.

I originally did this with LINQ, but started to get annoyed with it and decided for me it would be easier to construct queries wtih StringBuilder and use [Dapper.NET](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). So I still se the dmbl generated for my table (there are actually 31 tables, one for each day, but a view brings them together). And then create queries in my controller that go something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchParams sp)
{

    var db = new LogTableDataContext();
    var query = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    var fields = " Time, ClientIp, Method, Uri, Bytes, Server, Tr, TermState, UserAgent, Host ";
    query.Append(" SELECT ");

    if (sp.top.HasValue)
        query.Append(" Top ").Append(sp.top);
    query.Append(fields);
    query.Append(" from Logs ");

    query.Append(" WHERE 1=1 ");
    if (wherestrings.HasValue())
        query.Append(wherestrings);
    var resultsModel = new UberRows { rows = results, generated_query = query.ToString(), query_params = sp.GetPropertyNamesAndValues() };
    return View(resultsModel);
```

Where WHERE clauses are generated based on the GET parameters passed to the controller, something like:

```
public string GenerateWhereString()
{
    var wherestring = new StringBuilder();
    if (this.Uri.HasValue())
        wherestring.Append(" AND Uri = @Uri ");
    if (this.ClientIp.HasValue())
        wherestring.Append(" AND ClientIp = @ClientIP ");
    if (this.Server.HasValue())
```

UberRows simply has `public List<HAProxyLogViewer.Log> rows;` and I just render the results in div with jquery and the DataTable plugin since the result sets should generally be small.

### Now, to my question:

What I would also like to have his a bunch of queries that query the result set of the above search (How many hits to each Server, Average Response Time, etc).

I am guessing that the way to do this would be create a temp table with the results (since if I didn't I would have to generate the base results for each of those queries on things like response time for the result set), but since I am new to that, c#, and asp.mvc I am not sure in either the big picture of how that would work and be tied into MVC, my ORM, and the dmbl classes. Assuming I am correct about the temp table, how would I work with that?

So the pure SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT Time, ClientIp, Method, Uri, Bytes, Server, Tr, TermState, UserAgent, Host
INTO #resultsTable 
FROM Logs
WHERE 1=1 AND Time BETWEEN dateadd(minute, -1440, getutcdate()) and getutcdate()
AND UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)';

SELECT Time, ClientIp, Method, Uri, Bytes, Server, Tr, TermState, UserAgent, Host
FROM #resultsTable;

SELECT Server, COUNT(*)
FROM #resultsTable
GROUP BY Server;

SELECT AVG(Tr)
FROM #resultsTable;

DROP TABLE #resultsTable;
```

Comment: Are they dynamic queries, or queries you define ahead of time? If you have the data in memory, you can simply perform defined queries with LINQ. You can even do dynamic ones, if you're willing to parse expression trees.

Comment: @Tejs: Updated my question with how the various where clauses are generated -- so I believe it is dynamic if that is what you mean. Also, I think at this point I would like to stick with my StringBuilder if I can.

Comment: Ouch. I suggest looking at bltoolkit - a lot faster than any standard linnq implementation frmo microsoft and perfect for this kind of task.

Answer (score 2):

A Temporary Table will not last beyond the DB session that created it.  A Global Temporary Table can be shared across DB sessions but based on your scenario it might not be predictable when the sessions start and end so that might not give predictable results.

I would suggest creating a real table to hold the results and just query that. When the queries are done just DELETE all of the data. If it is possible to have multiple connections using different result sets (hence a Temp Table would have been great), then you can add a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER field as the "key" for which set of data to use for this set of queries.  Meaning, generate the GUID on the app side, and pass that into the query that populates the real table so that each of the queries against it can use that app-generated value as an additional WHERE clause.  When all of the queries against that "temporary" result set are done, do a DELETE based on that GUID. If for some reason the queries against a particular result set are disconnected and you don't know when the last one executes, add a DATETIME field to the result set and create a SQL Agent Job to DELETE records older than 30 or 60 minutes or whatever.

Edit:
Also, to be clear, IF all of the queries are really being done by a single connection then you *might* be able to still use a Temp Table if you enable MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) as I think MARS keeps a consistent session, but I am not sure as I have never used it.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a good idea. Not going to accept for now just to see what my other options are... I didn't even think about the session complications.